# WPF Datagrid and database interactions

Tags: c#, sql, database, wpf, datagrid

I am new in C# WPF. I want to know the best way to use a sql database(sqlite or sql server) with a datagrid(updating database from value change of the cells in the datagrid). Should I do it by writing my own sql statements for every cell value change, or can I use a binding to automatically update the database? Is there some kind of ORM to work with objects?
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework will be the easiest solution.

Check out this: [Databinding with WPF](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/wpf)